# select rows where values of two columns agree

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

if I have the following:

```
1 5 a
2 5 a
3 5 a
4 5 a
5 5 a
6 5 a
1 3 b
2 3 b
3 3 b
4 3 b
5 3 b
6 3 b
```

How do I only select rows where the two columns have the same value i.e.

```
5 5 a
3 3 b
```

in bash / awk / sed.

I know how to select rows with certain values using awk, but only when I specifiy the value.

Comment: Is it only numeric values?

Comment: yes it is only numbers. and Etan you have made me look silly. thanks. please post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just say:

```
$ awk '$1==$2' file
5 5 a
3 3 b
```

As you see, when the condition `$1 == $2` is accomplished, `awk` automatically prints the line.

Comment: I am amazed to see how answers on questions like this get these amount of votes.

Comment: Easy to answer also means more eyes. It also means 'correct' answers are obvious.

Comment: @Sobrique mmm it is not this "oh what a clever answer, I would've never thought about it" but -to me- "ah yes it's like that". But of course upvotes are always welcome : )

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[0] == $F[1]' file
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness:

bash

```
while read first second rest; do
    [[ $first -eq $second ]] && echo "$first $second $rest"
done < fi
```

or if content is not just integers:

```
while read first second rest; do
    [[ $first == $second ]] && echo "$first $second $rest"
done < file
```

sed

```
sed -En '/^([^ ]+) \1 /p' file
```

Comment: Probably better the `==` version, even though OP mentions it is supposed to just contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU grep):

```
grep '^\(\S\+\)\s\+\1\s\+' file
```